# QTableWidget from json in Python how to fill

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

I have such output:

```
{'heatpump': [{'Topic': 'TOP0', 'Name': 'Heatpump_State', 'Value': '1', 'Description': 'On'}, {'Topic': 'TOP1', 'Name': 'Pump_Flow', 'Value': '9.08', 'Description': 'l/min'},{.........}, {.......}]}
```

How to fill QTableWidget if we make such keys

```
keys = ["Topic", "Name", "Value", "Description"]
```

And how to make searchable by Name value, use QLabel field to achieve this ?

Adding part of code, how to enumerate rows here and add to the table all values and not the last one ?:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)


    data = {'heatpump': [{'Topic': 'TOP0', 'Name': 'Heatpump_State', 'Value': '1', 'Description': 'On'}, {'Topic': 'TOP1', 'Name': 'Pump_Flow', 'Value': '9.08', 'Description': 'l/min'}]}
    d = data
    keys = ["Topic", "Name", "Value", "Description"]
    labels = keys + ["ID"]
    #i = 0
    w = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5, len(labels))
    w.setColumnHidden(4, True)
    w.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)
    for record in d["heatpump"]:
        print(record)
        for i, (name, value) in enumerate(record.items()):
            print(i, name, value)
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(value)
            w.setItem(0, i, it)


    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the "header" labels (the keys), just iter through them to get the corresponding value:

```py
    keys = "Topic", "Name", "Value", "Description"
    for row, record in enumerate(d["heatpump"]):
        print(record)
        for column, key in enumerate(keys):
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(record.get(key, ""))
            w.setItem(row, column, it)
```